# How can I show Group-Members Profil Pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**First of all, my question is:**

How can i show all Members Profile Picture of my group, on a page ?

**What i know and what i have done:**

1. I have a Access Token
2. I have all User IDs of the group members

Is there any way like ... to show all pictures ? - or how have i do it ?

> https://graph.facebook.com/[GROUPID]/members?access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]

Answer (score 0):

```
$members = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$group_id.'/members?access_token='.$access_token);
foreach($members->data as $member) {
  echo('<li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$member->id.'/picture?type=square" />'.$member->name.'</li>');
}
```